# AZ deploy ARM template returns exceptions

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-cli, kafka-cluster

After weeks of successful deployment of KafkaCluster from AZ command line using ARM template, recently its not working anymore and no changes happened to `ARM template` or to `parameter`. after running the `AZ deployment command` it throws exceptions.

```
az deployment group create --resource-group XX --template-spec "/subscriptions/xxx/versions/1.0" --parameters ./environment/deploy/kafka/parameters.json --debug # to debug
```

After running the command, the template of Kafka is being printed with the right parameters, where at the end of the log there are some exceptions:

```
...
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/templateSpecs/versions",
  "name": "1.0"
}
azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 688, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 325, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 784, in default_command_handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/resource/custom.py", line 511, in deploy_arm_template_at_resource_group
    no_prompt=no_prompt, template_spec=template_spec)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/resource/custom.py", line 538, in _deploy_arm_template_at_resource_group
    no_prompt=no_prompt, template_spec=template_spec)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/resource/custom.py", line 830, in _prepare_deployment_properties_unmodified
    template_obj = show_resource(cmd=cmd, resource_ids=[template_spec]).properties['template']
KeyError: 'template'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/arm.py", line 103, in handle_template_based_exception
    raise CLIError(ex.inner_exception.error.message)
AttributeError: 'KeyError' object has no attribute 'inner_exception'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 215, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 654, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 718, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 709, in _run_job
    cmd_copy.exception_handler(ex)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/arm.py", line 105, in handle_template_based_exception
    raise CLIError(ex)
knack.util.CLIError: 'template'
```

What could be wrong here ?
Any suggestions is welcomed.

Comment: Could you please check if you have the right resource id of your template spec resource?

Comment: Yes I got the resource id using AZ command `az ts show --name KafkaClusterSpec --resource-group XXResources --version 1.0 --query id`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the parameters file which Jenkins uses to trigger deployment, simple way to fix to pass ARM template parameters from the command line instead reading them from a file.

```
--parameters 'clusterName=XX' 'clusterLoginUserName=XX' 'clusterLoginPassword=XX' 'location=XX' 'clusterVersion=4.0' 'clusterKind=XX' 'sshUserName=XX' 'sshPassword=XX' 'minTlsVersionNumber=1.2'
```